# How can I iterate through text two lines at a time?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a text file that I would like to go through and list every count each time a succession of two words appear. For example my desired output would look like this:

Sample input:

```
I am a man
```

desired output:

```
1 I am
1 am a
1 a man
```

How I thought about doing this is so:

```
cat $1 | sed "s/ /\n/g" | read  word1 && 
    while read word2;
    do
        echo "$word1    $word2";
        word1=word2;
    done
```

This gets an infinite loop though. Any help appreciated!

Comment: please update the question with sample input and the (complete) expected output; also, can a 2-word combo span lines, eg, would `one\nword` match `one word`?

Comment: @markp-fuso i just did, sorry

Comment: how about a sample input file with more than one line; do you want the counts for each line or for the whole file? and what about my other question ... would `one\nword` (`one` at end of first line, `word` at beginning of next line) count as `one word`?

Comment: Note: `word1=$word2` with the `$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

- counts are accumulated across the entire file (as opposed to restarting the counts for each new line)
- word pairs can span lines, eg, `one\nword` is the same as `one word`
- we're only interested in 2-word pairings, ie, no need to code for a dynamic number of words (eg, 3-words, 4-words)

Sample input data:

```
$ cat words.dat
I am a man
I am not a man I
am a man
```

One `awk` idea:

```
$ awk -v RS='' '                       # treat file as one loooong single record
    { for (i=1;i<NF;i++)               # loop through list of fields 1 - (NF-1)
          count[$(i)" "$(i+1)]++       # use field i and i+1 as array index
    }
END { for (i in count)                 # loop through array indices
          print count[i],i
    }
' words.dat
```

This generates:

```
2 am a
3 a man
1 am not
3 I am
1 not a
2 man I
```

**NOTE:** no sorting requirement was stated otherwise we could pipe the result to `sort`, or if using `GNU awk` we may be able to add an appropriate `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` statement

OP's original input:

```
$ awk -v RS='' '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) count[$(i)" "$(i+1)]++} END {for (i in count) print count[i],i}' <<< "I am a man"
1 am a
1 a man
1 I am
```

---

Removing the assumption about dynamic word counts ...

```
$ awk -v wcnt=2 -v RS='' '                  # <word_count> = 2; treat file as one loooong single record
NF>=wcnt { for (i=1;i<=(NF-wcnt+1);i++) {   # loop through list of fields 1 - (NF-<word_count>)
               pfx=key=""
               for (j=0;j<wcnt;j++) {       # build count[] index from <word_count> fields
                   key=key pfx $(j+i)
                   pfx=" "
               }
               count[key]++
           }
         } 

END      { for (i in count)                 # loop through array indices
               print count[i],i
         }
' words.dat
```

With `-v wcnt=2`:

```
2 am a
3 a man
1 am not
3 I am
1 not a
2 man I
```

With `-v wcnt=3`:

```
1 not a man
2 I am a
1 I am not
2 man I am
2 am a man
2 a man I
1 am not a
```

With `-v wcnt=5`:

```
1 I am a man I
1 I am not a man
1 am not a man I
1 am a man I am
1 man I am a man
1 man I am not a
1 a man I am not
1 not a man I am
1 a man I am a
```

With `-v wcnt=3` and `awk '...' <<< "I am a man"`:

```
1 I am a
1 am a man
```

With `-v wcnt=5` and `awk '...' <<< "I am a man"`:

```
# no output since less than wcnt=5 words to work with
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `read` twice in the `while` condition.

```
while read line1; read line2; do
    echo "$line1 $line2"
done <<EOF
1
a
2
b
EOF
```

will output

```
1 a
2 b
```

The loop exits when the second `read` fails, even if the first succeeds. If you will want to execute the body (even with an empty `line2`), move `read line2` into the body of the loop.

Comment: But that skips one combination right? For example for ` I am a man` I would like to have `I am, am a, a man`. Yours would just do `I am, a man`, right?

Comment: You didn't provide any sample input, and your question only asked about reading two lines of input at once. I assumed your `sed` command was producing the desired input to the loop.

Comment: I just did, my bad

Comment: If you replace ; with ||, each time it will read only one line.

Comment: @Philippe Right. Something about that felt off while I was writing it (`&&` was clearly wrong, but I didn't think `||` through enough.)

Answer (score 0):

With bash:

```sh
set -f         # for slurping in the words of the file, we want word splitting
               # but not glob expansion
words=( $(< "$1") )

for ((i = 1; i < ${#words[@]}; i++)); do
  printf "%s %s\n" "${words[i-1]}" "${words[i]}"
done
```

Given @chepner's input file, this outputs

```
1 a
a 2
2 b
```

---

A rewrite of your code: you need a grouping construct so that all the `read`s are reading from the same pipeline of data.

```sh
tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' < "$1" | {
  IFS= read -r word1
  while IFS= read -r word2; do 
    echo "$word1 $word2"
    word1=$word2
  done
}
```

---

For counting, the simplest method is to pipe the output into `| sort | uniq -c`
With the `words.dat` file from @markp-fuso, output from both these solutions is

```
      3 I am
      3 a man
      2 am a
      1 am not
      2 man I
      1 not a
```

The counting can be done in bash using an associative array:

```sh
declare -A pairs

for ((i = 1; i < ${#words[@]}; i++)); do
  key="${words[i-1]} ${words[i]}"
  pairs[$key]=$(( pairs[$key] + 1 ))
done

for key in "${!pairs[@]}"; do
  printf "%7d %s\n" "${pairs[$key]}" "$key"
done
```

```
      1 not a
      3 a man
      1 am not
      2 am a
      3 I am
      2 man I
```

Comment: do you have any idea why my while loop does not work

Comment: Because your code runs this `cat $1 | sed "s/ /\n/g" | read  word1` and then throws away the rest of the file. **Then** the while loop starts, and `read word2` is waiting for some data on stdin. This is the part that looks like an infinite loop. To test, type some text, hit enter then hit Ctrl+D. This is exactly why I added the braces in my answer

Comment: Additionally, because `read word1` is in a pipeline, that `read` is executed in a **subshell**, so `$word1` will no longer be available in the current shell